# How to fetch an array of Nested Type in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, arrays, scala, elasticsearch, scala-2.11

i have a following document

```
{
  "_index" : "Testdb",
  "_type" : "artWork",
  "_id" : "0",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"uuid":0
,"StatusHistoryList":[
     {"ArtWorkDate":"2015-08-26T19:05:55.137+05:00",
      "ArtworkStatus":"ACTIVE"
     }
                      ]
}
}
```

i want to fetch the value of array but i dont know how to do it please help me here is my code

```
val get=client.prepareGet("Testdb","artWork",Id.toString())
        .setOperationThreaded(false)
        .setFields("uuid","StatusHistoryList","_source")
        .execute()
        .actionGet()
//as i know howto fetch a single element from a document as i get uuid value accurately  
       var uuid=get.getField("uuid").getValue.toString().toInt
//how to get `StatusHistoryList` array elements ?
       var a=get.getField("StatusHistoryList").getValues.toArray()//as i am not sure is this correct or not
```

please help me

Comment: There are two [similar answers here](http://iswwwup.com/t/c358c7f8920b/how-to-retrive-stored-scala-mutable-set-from-elasticsearch.html), do they help?

Comment: this post is mine i asked this question on stack few months ago i know how to traverse an simple array but this time my array contains a doc so i am confused how to retrieve those fields in it